# The "beta" badge on the new "Jobs" button is distracting

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I see that drawing attention to new features is somehow important, but as someone who is not interested in jobs at all (which is also configured in my profile settings for about as long as that option is available), I would prefer not having my attention drawn to the Jobs tab due to the blue "beta" mark on it. It's about the same blue that also draws attention to new event entries on the profile page and bounty questions.

While I understand that new features need attention and their beta state needs to be communicated, I would like to see a less obtrusive way to announce the beta state of that particular feature. For example, a simple "(beta)" suffix using the same formatting as the "Jobs" text on the button would do the job just as well.

And while I'm at it: The "Create CV" link on the profile page is also drawing a lot more attention than it should, considering the setting "Not interested in jobs".

Comment: +1 I think it's the color in combination with the tag-like framing that render the beta badge more like a notification than anything else..

Comment: `.nav-jobs-beta { display:none !important; }` if you have an extension such as Stylish. https://userstyles.org/styles/122033/stackoverflow-remove-jobs-beta-tag

Comment: Agreed, perhaps they could also change the color so it's less distracting, like light grey.

Comment: It looks like highlighted text, and it's super distracting.

Comment: it's completely silly and should simply be deleted.  who gives a toss that one of SO's advertising features is "a beta!"?  answer - nobody other than people with stock options.  for goodness sake, delete to avoid embarrassment

Comment: I think that instead of the inline Beta tag, it should simply read "Jobs" without anything else EXCEPT that a sound snippet of a kazoo should play whenever that nav item comes into view of the user such as page load or scrolling.

Comment: This is "status-completed"?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

How about the following compromise?

**before:**

[image]

**after:**

[image]

Make the box a slightly darker gray than the menu itself. It still makes the mark visible but it's far less distracting and not easily mistaken for a notification or reputation change. I'd also find it a more natural fit design-wise.

Comment: Looks good enough to me.

Comment: Now we just gotta get it done :D

Comment: Needs more jQuery... `$('.nav-jobs-beta').remove();`

Comment: @TravisJ I'll be honest: I've used Gimp…

Comment: What's the `158` next to `Review`? Is that a Jobs thing? I don't use Careers.

Comment: @Arc676 it's the [suggested edits queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/) (for reviewing suggested edits) which [unlocks at 2k rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Comment: This is "status-completed"?

Answer (score 13):

The beta badge is a temporary UI element and we don't want to let a temporary UI element put a damper on anyone's day. So if you're not interested in jobs, and you've told us that on your profile here...

[image]

...we'll take the beta badge away so it isn't so distracting. That change is live now.

Comment: I like the jobs tab, just not the beta icon :) I think users in general are already used to live product being semi beta when released anyway (I am looking at you windows 10).

Comment: Wouldn't it apply also for "Open but not actively looking"?

Comment: Displaying the icon in flashy blue and being interested in jobs are two completely different things.

Comment: May I point out that "Not interested in Jobs" doesn't seem to stick too well? Every few days I seem to have to reapply that particular option.

Comment: @Wormbo: You may. You shouldn't have to do that. I'll see if I can find anything.

Comment: What if I am one of the other 2 options AND I don't like distracting UI elements?