# Jobs now larger than others

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The link for the jobs has a small CSS bug. It looks very large compared to the other buttons present on the same line.

[image]

This was seen on Firefox 42.0 (also reproduced on 43 - from comments)

Most probably - Problem is with rev 2015.12.18.3111

Comment: Just saw this also. Firefox 43.

Comment: Looking into this now.

Comment: status-by-design: jobs are very important you know.

Comment: @JasonPunyon Possible hint: I looks like it's caused by the negative margin on `.nav-jobs-beta`. Solutions include removing said margin, adding `white-space: nowrap` to the `a` tag, and removing excess whitespace.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: Yep, our conclusion too. We're cleaning it up.

Comment: @JonH Better they leave it for some time... It is looking nice :P

Comment: I have the same issue I thought that would be caused by my UHD screen.

Comment: Added the red circle

Comment: @JasonPunyon Looks like it's fixed.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Yep. They've pushed 3112.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While trying to do a good thing on [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312846/the-beta-badge-on-the-new-jobs-button-is-distracting) we accidentally made this tab bigger. And then deployed a jobs tab to the entire network. We're having a good day. How's your day going?

This should be fixed now.

Comment: *How's your day going?* ... Night here exams tomo. Leavin that, why you ain't wearing a hat? :-(

Comment: Lemme buy you a drink...I've had those kinds of days too.

Comment: Wow, you wore a hat on my request. That is so sweet of you. :)