# "Jobs Beta" makes me think I've highlighted something by accident

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

Hopefully this does not come off as complainy, ranty, or whiney but at least 243 times per day I will mistakenly see highlighted text out of the corner of my eye and try to click on white-space within the web page to de-highlight the "beta" tag within the Jobs tag.

I've come to realize that it looks a lot like highlighted text.

Is it possible to use a different shade of blue?

[image: Jobs beta]

Comment: I would like this to be changed as well, not for OP’s reasoning, but because the blue simply draws too much attention to it. Yes, “Jobs” on SO is a new thing, so it makes kind of sense to advertise it, but then again, it’s just a rebranded Careers without much new to see. As a long-term Careers user, I certainly don’t need it to be flashy. And the way it is promoted irritates me.

Comment: Join the club in the following thread... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312846/the-beta-badge-on-the-new-jobs-button-is-distracting#comment285266_312846

Comment: But [this button is so hard to spot and identify](https://www.facebook.com/officialstackoverflow/photos/a.10150577091689971.1073741825.11239244970/10150577088264971/?type=3&comment_id=10150577099829971&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R%22%7D)!!

Comment: I actually thought they did that on purpose.

Comment: @insys clearly my Googling skills have failed me! Good call.

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula They did, but for the (IMHO) wrong purpose.

Comment: As a temporary solution, we can remove it using a TamperMonkey script

Comment: @VarunAgw Yes, that is a possibility. Maybe you could make an answer out of it and provide the necessary instructions and JavaScript? Would IE users be able to use it as well?